# MPI_Recv: Receiving a different size than the one Sent

Tags: c, mpi

I am writing a program to check shortest path using the `MPI` library.
There are two scenarios:
Either I found a better path, in with case the first slot of the buffer will state `resultBuff[0] = 1` and I will need to go over the rest of the contents of the buffer to get the better path.
The other case is `resultBuff[0] = 0`, and I won't excpect any values in the other cells of the buffer.

Is it possible for me to use separate `MPI_Isend` calls:

In case I found a better path and stored it in `resultBuff[1]` to `resultBuff[10]`:

```
MPI_Isend((void*)sendBuff, 11, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

In case didn't found a better path:

```
MPI_Isend((void*)sendBuff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

And in both cases I'll use

```
MPI_Recv( (void*)resultBuff, 11, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

to receive the result.

Will this work?
If it does, would I save communication costs if don't send a better path?

Note: `resultBuff` is of size 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.   From the MPI standard and [man pages](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Recv.html) for MPI_Recv, "the count argument indicates the maximum length of a message; the actual number can be determined with [MPI_Get_count](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node35.html#node35)" which you call using the `status` object you got back from MPI_Recv().

As to saving communication costs, it probably won't -- such short messages are dominated by the latency of sending the message rather than the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send a message to say "I found nothing": the *lack* of a message can convey that information just as well. The receiver(s) can just periodically call [MPI_Test](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node50.html#SECTION00383000000000000000), and examine the status object to see whether a new message was received or not.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, it just goes around it.

Comment: I still need to know when the path calculation is over. I need to send a message stating "I'm done", only then will I know whether it found a better path or not.